# TeX-doc doesn't recognize most symbols and packages

Tags: auctex

When running `TeX-doc` on this buffer (with `?` indicating point)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geo?metry}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

not only is `geometry` not the default (there is no default provided), but the options for completion are mostly nonsense:

```
Click on a completion to select it.
In this buffer, type RET to select the completion near point.

Possible completions are:
APAamerican                            APAbritish
APAczech                               APAdutch
APAenglish                             APAgerman
APAgreek                               APAngerman
DDC-01                                 DDC-03
DDC-07                                 DDC-09
DDC-19                                 DDC-21
DDC-22                                 DDC-24
DDC-25                                 DDC-27
DDC-28                                 DDC-30
EuropeFlagBW                           EuropeFlagBlueCMYK
EuropeFlagCMYK                         EuropeFlagWB
README-run                             TCSgradlogo
TCSlogo                                TU_Logo_HKS41
TU_Logo_SW                             TU_Logo_WS
USEngLogo                              USEngLogo-BW
USEngLogo-BW-top                       USEngLogo-top
USleaf-BW                              USleaf-gold
USleaf-grey                            USleaf-maroon
USlogo                                 USlogo-BW
USlogo-BW-left                         USlogo-BW-stack
USlogo-BW-top                          USlogo-left
USlogo-stack                           USlogo-top
angleHG                                arrow-glow
atari                                  barre-rico
beamericonarticle                      beamericonarticle.20
beamericonbook                         beamericonbook.20
beamericononline                       beamericononline.20
bibitem                                blue-inverted-arrow
budget                                 bullet-glow
but                                    button
button1c                               button1e
buttonec                               buttonee
buttongc                               buttonge
cmp-logo                               context-version
cow                                    dccpaper-by
dice                                   europasslogo
example-grid-100x100bp                 example-grid-100x100pt
example-image                          example-image-10x16
example-image-16x10                    example-image-16x9
example-image-1x1                      example-image-4x3
example-image-9x16                     example-image-a
example-image-a3                       example-image-a3-landscape
example-image-a4                       example-image-a4-landscape
example-image-a5                       example-image-a5-landscape
example-image-b                        example-image-c
example-image-golden                   example-image-golden-upright
example-image-letter                   example-image-letter-landscape
example_graph_for_ascii_displayer      fancytipmark
files                                  flower
ghsystem_acid                          ghsystem_acid-8
ghsystem_aqpol                         ghsystem_bottle
ghsystem_bottle-2-black                ghsystem_bottle-2-white
ghsystem_exclam                        ghsystem_explos
ghsystem_explos-1                      ghsystem_explos-2
ghsystem_explos-3                      ghsystem_explos-4
ghsystem_explos-5                      ghsystem_explos-6
ghsystem_flame                         ghsystem_flame-2-black
ghsystem_flame-2-white                 ghsystem_flame-3-black
ghsystem_flame-3-white                 ghsystem_flame-4-1
ghsystem_flame-4-2                     ghsystem_flame-4-3-black
ghsystem_flame-4-3-white               ghsystem_flame-5-2-black
ghsystem_flame-5-2-white               ghsystem_flame-O
ghsystem_flame-O-5-1                   ghsystem_health
ghsystem_skull                         ghsystem_skull-2
ghsystem_skull-6                       green-bullet-on-blue
green-bullet-on-blue-wc                green-bullet-on-white
green-inverted-arrow                   gyom
hand                                   hyph-af.chr
hyph-af.hyp                            hyph-af.lic
hyph-af.pat                            hyph-as.chr
hyph-as.hyp                            hyph-as.lic
hyph-as.pat                            hyph-bg.chr
hyph-bg.hyp                            hyph-bg.lic
hyph-bg.pat                            hyph-bn.chr
hyph-bn.hyp                            hyph-bn.lic
hyph-bn.pat                            hyph-ca.chr
hyph-ca.hyp                            hyph-ca.lic
hyph-ca.pat                            hyph-cop.chr
hyph-cop.hyp                           hyph-cop.lic
hyph-cop.pat                           hyph-cs.chr
hyph-cs.hyp                            hyph-cs.lic
hyph-cs.pat                            hyph-cy.chr
hyph-cy.hyp                            hyph-cy.lic
hyph-cy.pat                            hyph-da.chr
hyph-da.hyp                            hyph-da.lic
hyph-da.pat                            hyph-de-1901.chr
hyph-de-1901.hyp                       hyph-de-1901.lic
hyph-de-1901.pat                       hyph-de-1996.chr
hyph-de-1996.hyp                       hyph-de-1996.lic
hyph-de-1996.pat                       hyph-de-ch-1901.chr
hyph-de-ch-1901.hyp                    hyph-de-ch-1901.lic
hyph-de-ch-1901.pat                    hyph-el-monoton.chr
hyph-el-monoton.hyp                    hyph-el-monoton.lic
hyph-el-monoton.pat                    hyph-el-polyton.chr
hyph-el-polyton.hyp                    hyph-el-polyton.lic
hyph-el-polyton.pat                    hyph-en-gb.chr
hyph-en-gb.hyp                         hyph-en-gb.lic
hyph-en-gb.pat                         hyph-en-us.chr
hyph-en-us.hyp                         hyph-en-us.lic
hyph-en-us.pat                         hyph-eo.chr
hyph-eo.hyp                            hyph-eo.lic
hyph-eo.pat                            hyph-es.chr
hyph-es.hyp                            hyph-es.lic
hyph-es.pat                            hyph-et.chr
hyph-et.hyp                            hyph-et.lic
hyph-et.pat                            hyph-eu.chr
hyph-eu.hyp                            hyph-eu.lic
hyph-eu.pat                            hyph-fi.chr
hyph-fi.hyp                            hyph-fi.lic
hyph-fi.pat                            hyph-fr.chr
hyph-fr.hyp                            hyph-fr.lic
hyph-fr.pat                            hyph-fur.chr
hyph-fur.hyp                           hyph-fur.lic
hyph-fur.pat                           hyph-ga.chr
hyph-ga.hyp                            hyph-ga.lic
hyph-ga.pat                            hyph-gl.chr
hyph-gl.hyp                            hyph-gl.lic
hyph-gl.pat                            hyph-grc.chr
hyph-grc.hyp                           hyph-grc.lic
hyph-grc.pat                           hyph-gu.chr
hyph-gu.hyp                            hyph-gu.lic
hyph-gu.pat                            hyph-hi.chr
hyph-hi.hyp                            hyph-hi.lic
hyph-hi.pat                            hyph-hr.chr
hyph-hr.hyp                            hyph-hr.lic
hyph-hr.pat                            hyph-hsb.chr
hyph-hsb.hyp                           hyph-hsb.lic
hyph-hsb.pat                           hyph-hu.chr
hyph-hu.hyp                            hyph-hu.lic
hyph-hu.pat                            hyph-hy.chr
hyph-hy.hyp                            hyph-hy.lic
hyph-hy.pat                            hyph-ia.chr
hyph-ia.hyp                            hyph-ia.lic
hyph-ia.pat                            hyph-id.chr
hyph-id.hyp                            hyph-id.lic
hyph-id.pat                            hyph-is.chr
hyph-is.hyp                            hyph-is.lic
hyph-is.pat                            hyph-it.chr
hyph-it.hyp                            hyph-it.lic
hyph-it.pat                            hyph-ka.chr
hyph-ka.hyp                            hyph-ka.lic
hyph-ka.pat                            hyph-kmr.chr
hyph-kmr.hyp                           hyph-kmr.lic
hyph-kmr.pat                           hyph-kn.chr
hyph-kn.hyp                            hyph-kn.lic
hyph-kn.pat                            hyph-la-x-classic.chr
hyph-la-x-classic.hyp                  hyph-la-x-classic.lic
hyph-la-x-classic.pat                  hyph-la.chr
hyph-la.hyp                            hyph-la.lic
hyph-la.pat                            hyph-lt.chr
hyph-lt.hyp                            hyph-lt.lic
hyph-lt.pat                            hyph-lv.chr
hyph-lv.hyp                            hyph-lv.lic
hyph-lv.pat                            hyph-ml.chr
hyph-ml.hyp                            hyph-ml.lic
hyph-ml.pat                            hyph-mn-cyrl.chr
hyph-mn-cyrl.hyp                       hyph-mn-cyrl.lic
hyph-mn-cyrl.pat                       hyph-mr.chr
hyph-mr.hyp                            hyph-mr.lic
hyph-mr.pat                            hyph-mul-ethi.chr
hyph-mul-ethi.hyp                      hyph-mul-ethi.lic
hyph-mul-ethi.pat                      hyph-nb.chr
hyph-nb.hyp                            hyph-nb.lic
hyph-nb.pat                            hyph-nl.chr
hyph-nl.hyp                            hyph-nl.lic
hyph-nl.pat                            hyph-nn.chr
hyph-nn.hyp                            hyph-nn.lic
hyph-nn.pat                            hyph-or.chr
hyph-or.hyp                            hyph-or.lic
hyph-or.pat                            hyph-pa.chr
hyph-pa.hyp                            hyph-pa.lic
hyph-pa.pat                            hyph-pl.chr
hyph-pl.hyp                            hyph-pl.lic
hyph-pl.pat                            hyph-pms.chr
hyph-pms.hyp                           hyph-pms.lic
hyph-pms.pat                           hyph-pt.chr
hyph-pt.hyp                            hyph-pt.lic
hyph-pt.pat                            hyph-rm.chr
hyph-rm.hyp                            hyph-rm.lic
hyph-rm.pat                            hyph-ro.chr
hyph-ro.hyp                            hyph-ro.lic
hyph-ro.pat                            hyph-ru.chr
hyph-ru.hyp                            hyph-ru.lic
hyph-ru.pat                            hyph-sa.chr
hyph-sa.hyp                            hyph-sa.lic
hyph-sa.pat                            hyph-sh-cyrl.chr
hyph-sh-cyrl.hyp                       hyph-sh-cyrl.lic
hyph-sh-cyrl.pat                       hyph-sh-latn.chr
hyph-sh-latn.hyp                       hyph-sh-latn.lic
hyph-sh-latn.pat                       hyph-sk.chr
hyph-sk.hyp                            hyph-sk.lic
hyph-sk.pat                            hyph-sl.chr
hyph-sl.hyp                            hyph-sl.lic
hyph-sl.pat                            hyph-sr-cyrl.chr
hyph-sr-cyrl.hyp                       hyph-sr-cyrl.lic
hyph-sr-cyrl.pat                       hyph-sv.chr
hyph-sv.hyp                            hyph-sv.lic
hyph-sv.pat                            hyph-ta.chr
hyph-ta.hyp                            hyph-ta.lic
hyph-ta.pat                            hyph-te.chr
hyph-te.hyp                            hyph-te.lic
hyph-te.pat                            hyph-th.chr
hyph-th.hyp                            hyph-th.lic
hyph-th.pat                            hyph-tk.chr
hyph-tk.hyp                            hyph-tk.lic
hyph-tk.pat                            hyph-tr.chr
hyph-tr.hyp                            hyph-tr.lic
hyph-tr.pat                            hyph-uk.chr
hyph-uk.hyp                            hyph-uk.lic
hyph-uk.pat                            hyph-zh-latn-pinyin.chr
hyph-zh-latn-pinyin.hyp                hyph-zh-latn-pinyin.lic
hyph-zh-latn-pinyin.pat                ifmlogoc
ifmlogog                               info
keystroke_left                         keystroke_middle
keystroke_right                        left
lily-crescHairpin                      lily-crotchet
lily-crotchetDotted                    lily-crotchetDottedDouble
lily-crotchetDottedDoubleDown          lily-crotchetDottedDown
lily-crotchetDown                      lily-decrescHairpin
lily-demisemiquaver                    lily-demisemiquaverDotted
lily-demisemiquaverDottedDouble        lily-demisemiquaverDottedDoubleDown
lily-demisemiquaverDottedDown          lily-demisemiquaverDown
lily-fancyExample                      lily-halfNote
lily-halfNoteDotted                    lily-halfNoteDottedDouble
lily-halfNoteDottedDoubleDown          lily-halfNoteDottedDown
lily-halfNoteDown                      lily-quaver
lily-quaverDotted                      lily-quaverDottedDouble
lily-quaverDottedDoubleDdown           lily-quaverDottedDoubleDown
lily-quaverDottedDown                  lily-quaverDown
lily-semiquaver                        lily-semiquaverDotted
lily-semiquaverDottedDouble            lily-semiquaverDottedDoubleDown
lily-semiquaverDottedDown              lily-semiquaverDown
lily-threeBeamedQuavers                lily-threeBeamedQuaversI
lily-threeBeamedQuaversII              lily-threeBeamedQuaversIII
lily-twoBeamedQuavers                  lines
metablue                               metagray
metagreen                              metalgray
overlay                                overlay0
overlay1                               overlay10
overlay2                               overlay3
overlay4                               overlay5
overlay6                               overlay7
overlay8                               overlay9
pkulogo                                pkuword
powerdot-default                       red-bullet-on-blue
red-bullet-on-blue-wc                  red-bullet-on-white
red-inverted-arrow                     rico
rico_bullet1                           rico_bullet2
rico_bullet3                           right
rotation                               rule-glow
sample                                 sapienza-MLblack-pos
sapienza-MLred-pos                     status-files
status-lua                             t-transliterator
ua_color                               udesoftec-cover-uba
udesoftec-cover-ude-de                 udesoftec-cover-ude-en
ul_p                                   warn
yellow-bullet-on-blue                  yellow-bullet-on-blue-wc
yellow-bullet-on-white
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: TeX-doc function is IMHO overly complicated, it should be really fixed some day. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/23634211